# Chrome ignoring hashes in URL

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, url

I've spent quite a while trying to find answers for this issue, but haven't had any success. Basically I need to scroll the user to the contact portion of the website when they go to [healthdollars.com/#contact](http://healthdollars.com/#contact). This works just fine in Safari, but in Chrome I haven't had any luck. I've tried using jQuery/Javascript to force the browser to scroll down, but I haven't been able to.

Does anyone have any ideas? It's driving me crazy - especially since it's such a simple thing to do.

Comment: It works for me in chrome when I click on your link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a full answer but in Chrome if you disable Javascript I believe you get the desired behavior. This makes me believe that something in your JavaScript is preventing default browser behavior.

Comment: It turns out that it was something Modernizr was doing. Once I removed it, things started working again.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the target element doesn't exist when when page first loads. I don't have any problem if I navigate to the page and then add the hash.

```
if (window.location.hash.length && $(location.hash)) {
  window.scrollTo(0, $(location.hash).offset().top)
}
```

check for a hash, find the element's page offset, and scroll there (x, y).

edit: I noticed that, in fact, the page starts at #contact, then scrolls back to the top. I agree with the other answerer that there's something on your page that's scrolling you to the top. I'd search for that before adding a hack.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JS, for example` if you have JQuery.

```
$(function(){
  // get the selector to scroll (#contact)
  var $to = $(window.location.hash);

  // jquery animate
  $('html'/* or body */).animate({ scrollTop: $to.offset().top });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute doesn't exists in HTML 5 so chrome looks to have made the name attribute obsolete when you use the DOCTYPE html.

The other browsers have yet to catch up.

Change

```
<a name="contact"></a>
```

to

```
<a id="contact"></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this workaround with vanilla javascript can be useful:

```
// Get the HTMLElement that you want to scroll to. 
var element = document.querySelector('#contact');
// Stories the height of element in the page.
var elementHeight = element.scrollHeight;
// Get the HTMLElement that will fire the scroll on{event}.
var trigger = document.querySelector('[href="#contact"]');    
trigger.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  // Hide the hash from URL.
  event.preventDefault();
  // Call the scrollTo(width, height) method of window, for example.
  window.scrollTo(0, elementHeight);
})
```